# Point of reflection on a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find the point on a circle where a light source is reflected to the focal point of a camera...

So I have the coordinates of the light source, the focal point and the centre of a circle. I believe the light will reflect at an angle equal to the incident angle. I have tried forming equations with this information but I always seem to have too many unknowns...

[Diagram of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h68qe.jpg)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Since you are new to this site, don't inulcate the habit of leaving answers unaccepted(Check the tick mark). If you have any problems with the answer, comment your doubt and the answerer will clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\tan A={y_1-y_p\over x_1-x_p}\ ;\ \tan B={y_0-y_p\over x_0-x_p}\ \&\ \tan C={y_2-y_p\over x_2-x_p}$

Since incident angle equals reflected angle,at $(x_p,y_p)$, so $$\tan (A-B)=\tan (B-C)\implies {\tan A-\tan B\over 1+\tan A\tan B}={\tan B-\tan C\over 1+\tan B\tan C}$$

Moreover, since $x_p,y_p$ must be on a **circle**, you must know its radius$(=r)$: there goes another equation $$(x_0-x_p)^2+(y_0-y_p)^2=r^2$$
$2$ equation and $2$ unknowns ,BINGO!

Comment: Aren't there two unknowns? Xp and Yp?

Comment: @user385736 I thought the other equation was trivial!

Comment: I was nearly there it just confused me that it wasn't mentioned, thanks!

Comment: @user385736 No problem! People (including me) often miss much sillier things than this! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier, I limit all the points to the first quadrant and I also assume that the mirror surface is the horizontal tangent line y = k. Our target is to find k.

[image]

Let R be the reflection of Q about the line y = k. Because of the angle of incidence = angle of reflection, we have two sets of equal angles (red and green). Then, $R = (x_2, 2k – y_2)$.

Equation of PR is $L :\dfrac {y – y_1}{x – x_1} = \dfrac {(2k – y_2) – y_1}{x_2 – x_1}$.

Solving L and y = k, we will get the co-ordinates of O which is precisely $(x_0, k)$. Then we have one equation and only one unknown.

Note:- Special treatment will be needed in cases like $x_1 = x_2$ etc.